# Obtaining origin of Text from UITextView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitextview, xcode4.5

**-Goal: Get the Origin of a particular section of Text in a UITextView**

Below is a link to a Screenshot of an app I am working on. Please view it as it is easier to explain with it.
Image Link: [ScreenShot](http://img28.imageshack.us/img28/4638/screenshot20130603at907.png)

This is a start to a **Fill in the Blanks** style game. I am currently trying to get the x,y coordinates of each of the underscores. When a word on the bottom of the screen is tapped it will move to the next available underscore space.

Currently I have written this code to do what I need, but it is very ugly, barely works AND is not very flexible. See Below:

```
        // self.mainTextView is where the text with the underscores is coming from
        NSString *text = self.mainTextView.text;
        NSString *substring = [text substringToIndex:[text rangeOfString:@"__________"].location];



        CGSize size = [substring sizeWithFont:self.mainTextView.font];


        CGPoint p = CGPointMake((int)size.width % (int)self.mainTextView.frame.size.width, ((int)size.width / (int)self.mainTextView.frame.size.width) * size.height);




        // What is going on here is for some reason everytime there is a new
        // line my x coordinate is offset by what seems to be 10 pixels...
        // So was my ugly fix for it.. 
        // The UITextView width is 280

        CGRect mainTextFrame = [self.mainTextView frame];

        p.x = p.x + mainTextFrame.origin.x + 9;

        if ((int)size.width > 280) {
            NSLog(@"width: 280");
            p.x = p.x + mainTextFrame.origin.x + 10;
        }
        if ((int)size.width > 560) {
            NSLog(@"width: 560");
            p.x = p.x + mainTextFrame.origin.x + 12;

        }
        if ((int)size.width > 840) {
            p.x = p.x + mainTextFrame.origin.x + 14;

        }

        p.y = p.y + mainTextFrame.origin.y + 5;

        // Sender is the button that was pressed
        newFrame = [sender frame];
        newFrame.origin = p;

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent|UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{

                         [sender setFrame:newFrame];
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){

                     }
         ];
```

So the the best question for me to ask is
**What is a better way of going about this?** And or do you have any suggestions? How would you go about this?

Thank you for your time in advance.

Comment: you want to get location of ____ or u want to highlight it?

Comment: I want to get the Location of ______

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than manually searching each occurrence of the underscore. make use of **`NSRegularExpression`** Which makes your task so simple and easy. After the matched Strings are found then make use of the **`NSTextCheckingResult`** to get the location of each matched strings.

**`More Explaination:`**

You can make use of the **regular expression** inorder get all the occurence of the underscore.This is obtanied using the following code.

```
NSError *error = NULL;
NSString *pattern = @"_*_";  // pattern to search underscore.
NSString *string = self.textView.text;
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, string.length);
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:string options:NSMatchingProgress range:range];
```

Once you get all the Matching Patterns  you can get the location of the matched strings using the following code.

```
[matches enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSTextCheckingResult class]])
{
    NSTextCheckingResult *match = (NSTextCheckingResult *)obj;
    CGRect rect = [self frameOfTextRange:match.range inTextView:self.textView]; 
   //get location of all the matched strings.

}
}];
```

Hope this answers all your concerns!

Comment: I am not familiar with RegularExpressions. on the `NSArray *matches` I am receiving a warning which is the following: `xcode implicit conversion from enumeration type 'enum NSMatchingFlags' to different type NSMatchingOptions`

Comment: Just change the value of  option with `NSMatchingReportCompletion`

Comment: One other question is the line `CGRect rect = [self frameOfTextRange:match.ra.....` What is `self` supposed to be? The TextView? Sorry if thats a dumb question, just need to be sure

Comment: Hey Vinayak Kini, don't worry I didn't forget about you, was just testing your code in with mine. It works, so thank you very much for your time :-) Sorry if it was a bit frustrating for you, but I gotta start somewhere. Thanks again dude!

Comment: Not at all Frustrating! always Happy to help.. I am ready to solve few more queries if you have... :)

Comment: I don't have any other questions right now. I prefer to try and figure stuff out on my own and then if I get to a spot I can't get past then I ask questions. But perhaps we shall run into each other again. Thanks again dude! :D