# How to get text rect in UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextview

I am stuck with a getting frame rect of the text in UItextView I am using this code `

```
UITextPosition *Pos2 = [textView positionFromPosition: drawTextView.endOfDocument offset: 0];
    UITextPosition *Pos1 = [textView positionFromPosition: drawTextView.endOfDocument offset: -[textView.text length]];

    UITextRange *range = [textView textRangeFromPosition:Pos1 toPosition:Pos2];

    CGRect result1 = [textView firstRectForRange:(UITextRange *)range ];
```

`but it returns me`origin=(x=+Inf, y=+Inf) size=(width=0, height=0)`

Answer (score 2):

Check this :

```
CGRect size = [myTextView.text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(textView.frame.size.width, Max_height)
                                                     options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                                  attributes:attributesDictionary
                                                     context:nil];
NSLog(@"height : %@" size.height);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get it by using following code

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{   
    CGRect rc = [textView bounds];
    rc = [textView convertRect:rc toView:superViewOfTextView];
    .
    .
    .
    //Put your logic.

}
```

For get text **width and height** use

```
CGFloat width = [self.txtView.text length];
CGFloat height = [self.txtView.text sizeWithFont:setFontWithSize constrainedToSize:self.txtView.frame.size.width lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
```

Comment: I need the frame rect for the text in UItextView.

Comment: can you please tell me how can I get x and y.

Comment: @Suyash - check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16909843/obtaining-origin-of-text-from-uitextview